# Prove that the mapping $\psi : L(V,W) \rightarrow L(W^*, V^*)$ given by $\psi(T) = T^t$ is an isomorphism.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, inner-products

Let $V,W$ be finite-dimensional vector spaces over the same field $\mathbb{F}$ and let $L(V,W)$ be the vector space of $\mathbb{F}$-linear transformations from $V$ to $W$.

Prove that the mapping $\psi : L(V,W) → L(W^*, V^*)$ given by $\psi(T) = T^t$ is an isomorphism.

---

notation and definition:

$V^*$ is the dual space of $V$.

$T^t$ is the transpose of $T$.

Comment: And what have you tried?

Comment: I need to check that ψ is one one and onto or ψ has an inverse.

Comment: g:V--(V*)* is a canonical map

Comment: h:W--(W*)* is a canonical map

Comment: Can we say L(W**,V**)=L(W,V) ?

Comment: construct another function phi:L(W*,V*)-->L(W**,V**)=?=L(W,V) by phi(S)=S^t, then ψ o phi=phi o ψ = Id.

Comment: Because I change account, I post two question's webiste I asked before for convenient searching.http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/761742/inner-product-space-dual-space-proof-about-isomorphism http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/761379/v-uw-then-prove-that-v-w-is-isomorphic-to-w0

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $\psi(T)=0=T^t$. Then $T=(T^t)^t=(0)^t=0$, so that ker$(\psi)={0}$.

ok, it needs to be mentioned that the function $\psi$, in the way you have defined it, is actually acting on the matrix representations of the linear transformations, and not the linear transformations themselves, so supposing dim$(V)=n$ and dim$(W)=m$ we actually have a composition of isomorphisms $\phi_1 \circ \psi \circ \phi_2^{-1}$, where $\phi:L(V,W) \rightarrow M_{m \times n}(\mathbb{F})$ sends each linear transformation to its matrix representation and similarly $\phi_2 :L(W^*,V^*) \rightarrow M_{n \times m}(\mathbb{F})$ sends each linear transformation between the dual spaces to its matrix representation.

Anyway, through the composition of isomorphisms you have an isomorphism between $L(V,W)$ and $L(W^*,V^*)$ as required.